# I'm unable to boot Ubuntu after a CPU change

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel, cpu, amd-processor

I've recently replaced my old CPU, an AMD Phenom II X4 945, with an FX-8350 processor and since then, I am unable to boot my old system or a live CD of Ubuntu 16.04.

When deleting the `quiet splash` boot parameter, the boot messages on the screen halt at:

> [ 0.297065] ... event mask: 000000000000003f

(That's 14 zeroes, as can be seen in the attached image) with a continously blinking cursor.

The processor seems to be fine, as the memtest86+, included in Grub, runs without any issues for an extended period of time.

What can be done to fix this problem?

Here is a photo of the screen output:

[image]

Comment: Can you boot a live session of any other linux distro (or another version of Ubuntu)? Can you think of any changes of the BIOS/UEFI menu settings?

Comment: Hi sudodus, unfortunately I don't have any other live systems at hand. However, I apparently managed to boot the system by disabling the C1E/C6 functions in the CPU BIOS configuration. I don't know how stable the system is now, but could this have been an issue?

Comment: Maybe. Let us hope that someone who knows will read this and reply. Otherwise 'google is your friend'. Anyway, I'm glad that you made the computer boot, and can gradually learn more about how it works with the new CPU :-)

Comment: C1E -- Stops all CPU internal clocks.  C6 -- Deep Power Down Reduces the CPU internal voltage to any value, including 0 V. --- Read more at http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-cpu-c-states-power-saving-modes/#vWRVgq47GxYBlLTp.99